# Custom header in my detail table

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a grid with a detail table. When I do a multiple sort on that sub grid I would like the UI changed to reflect in which order the sorting is in. I have attached two screen shots representing what I want. I would prefer the header option. The problem is that the user can not tell which sort is the prominent one.

How would I achieve this using telerik grids? I can not find out how to put a header on the GridTableView or inside the detail table.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

[image: Sort information in the columns][image: Sort information in the expanded grid]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched all my grids to KendoUI Grids and took advantage of the clients commands and manipulated the columns via jquery.